# How does the Fourier picture relate to non-commutativity?

Tags: operators, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, observables

A compelling [video by 3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4) visualizes the uncertainty principle with Fourier transforms. The gap I'm trying to bridge is between this "Fourier picture" and the matrix-based statement $[\hat{X}, \hat{P}] \neq 0$ which basically says that the eigenbases of the conjugate variables are irreconcilably misaligned.

To what extent do the Fourier and matrix pictures overlap/differ?

PS: Please keep the answer accessible to, say, an upper undergraduate in physics. I don't have a PhD in math.

Comment: Have you seen the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Wave_mechanics_interpretation) on this topic? There is a link between these two.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/318962/50583

Answer (score 1):

Take $h$ to be the reduced Plack's constant here.

In quantum mechanics, one usually starts with the fact that, in the eigenbasis of $X$, momentum is the operator $-ih\frac{d}{dx}$. It's a postulate. Some inspiration for this can be gained from plain waves and a De Broglie relation.

A general plane wave-function, $\psi(x)=e^{i\omega x}$, has a definite momentum $p=\omega h$ (De-broglie relation). So these are the eigenfunctions of the momentum operator. The momentum operator itself will be the operator satisfying

$$P e^{i\omega x}=h\omega e^{i\omega x}=pe^{i\omega x}$$

Turns out, $P=-ih\frac{d}{dx}$. This is not out of the blue. It's well-known that the eigenfunctions of the derivative are exponentials, almost by definition.

Since we have the eigenvectors of $P$, we can change between $X$ basis and $P$ basis using the formula:

$\psi (p)=\langle p| \psi\rangle$, where $|p\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $P$.

$$\psi (p)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \psi (x) e^{-\frac{ipx}{h}}dx$$

This is the Fourier transform you saw in the video.

If you're unfamiliar with this notation, it's just a dot product. To find the component $v(k)$ of a vector $\vec{v}$ in the direction of a (unit) vector $\vec{k}$, we do $v(k)=\vec{k}\cdot {\vec{v}}=\sum v_i k_i$. The sum becomes an integral for functions.

As for $[X,P]=ih$, you can calculate this. The action of $X$ is $X\psi (x)= x\psi (x)$. Why? If $\psi(x)$ has a close to definite position, say it's peaked near $x_0$ and zero everywhere else, then $X\psi (x)=x_0\psi (x)$. $X$ makes the eigenvalues  $x_0$ of position pop up when it's operated on states of definite position (i.e. eigenvectors of position). So $X$ is the position operator.

Now you can verify:

$$(XP-PX)\psi(x)=-ihx\frac{d}{dx}\psi (x)+ih\frac{d}{dx}(x\psi(x))=ih\psi (x)$$

$$XP-PX=ih$$

Intuitively, you can see that $X$ and $P$ have no eigenvectors in common. The eigenvectors of $P$, expressed in the $x$ basis, are waves stretched for the entire number line. The eigenvectors of $X$ are functions sharply peaked at some $x$ (peak tends to infinity) and zero everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn’t a deep relation: for instance the uncertainty principle holds for angular momenta in the Robertson form $\Delta A\Delta B\ge \langle [A,B]\rangle$ which is state dependent and has nothing to do with FT.

It’s a coincidence that the form of the Fourier relation agrees with HUP for $x$ and $p$.  The symbol also have different meaning as in the case of Fourier this is a statement that to synthesize a pulse of width $\Delta x$ you need a momentum spread $\Delta p$ as least sufficiently wide to satisfy the (approximate) inequality, where in HUP $\Delta x$ or $\Delta p$ refer to spread of outcomes for a collection ideally prepared systems.