# Can the Einstein tensor be written as an integral over real spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, phase-space

### Background

We know the Stress-energy tensor can be written as:

$$ T^{\mu \nu} = \int \mathcal{N}(x,p,t) p^\mu \otimes p^\nu \frac{d V_p}{E}$$

where $\mathcal{N}(x,p,t)$ is the distribution function, $p^\mu$ is the $4$ momentum, $p^0 = E$ is the energy and $d V_p$ is the momentum phase space.

### Question

Can the Einstein Tensor also be written as an integral over real (not phase) space? If so, what? I think this would be really interesting since that would mean General relativity is telling us something about how real space relates to momentum space.

Comment: Your stress energy tensor can only be written that way because of certain assumptions on the composition of it (it being composed of classical particles). It's not true in general and certainly doesn't seem to apply to the Einstein tensor part.

Comment: @Raskolnikov I was thinking of classical general relativity without electromagnetism

Comment: @KP99 I wasn't thinking of doing anything quantum. In classical mechanics they are independent variables: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/318964/150174

Comment: What do you mean? $G_{\mu\nu}(x)$ and $T_{\mu\nu}(x)$ refer to a single point $x$ in spacetime; there is no spacetime integration.

Comment: It is unclear what the question is about. Are you looking for an integral representation of Einstein equations? Is this a question about Einstein-Vlasov (or similar) system, where your expression for SE tensor applies? Or are interested in averaging problem in GR and in coarse-grained Einstein tensor?

Comment: The representation of the stress-energy tensor you've written down is an integration over the momentum of particles at position $x$, assuming that the matter consists of some kind of gas. In classical general relativity, spacetime is not made of particles, so there is no analogous momentum space integration.

Comment: @Qmechanic a dirac delta function might help?

Comment: @A.V.S. Einstein vaslov meeting might help?